# What is the characteristic of a projective plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, projective-geometry

Let $p \in \mathbb{N}$ be a prime number and $E$ the projective plane induced by the one and two dimensional linear subspaces of $(\mathbb{F}_p)^3$. I shall prove, that the characteristic of $E$ is equal to $p$. However I dont know what is meant by the characteristic of a projective plane and how it is defined. Can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Does this mean anything to you? It's a topological definition of the Euler characteristic, so it should work for the projective plane, but it's pretty technical. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Topological_definition

Comment: @EricStucky No sorry, found that as well, but I could not make a link to the projectiv plane.

Comment: @anon, the projective plane in question is the finite geometry that has for its points the 1-dimensional subspaces of $(F_p)^3$ and for its lines the 2-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: What was meant by the question was the **order** of the Projective plane, [described here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Finite_field_planes). Don't ask me why they did call it characteristic on the homework sheet. Could be that it is the Euler characteristic of a projectiv plane, but I can't jugde on that one.

Comment: Each time I see your [user name](http://www.dict.cc/german-english/hatschi.html) I feel the urge to say: **[Geeesundheit!!!](http://www.dict.cc/?s=gesundheit)**. This time I couldn't resist.

Answer (score 2):

OP has clarified that what was meant was the *order* of the projective plane, but hasn't indicated what definition of order has been given in class. The order is one less than the number of points on a line, but I don't know whether that's the definition of order or a theorem that follows from some other definition, and I don't know whether OP is allowed to use this. Anyway, let's show that the number of points on a line is $p+1$ (and therefore the order is $p$).

Remember that in this context the lines are 2-dimensional subspaces of a 3-dimensional vector space over a field of $p$ elements, and the points are the 1-dimensional subspaces. So we want to show that any 2-dimensional subspace contains $p+1$ 1-dimensional subspaces.

A 1-dimensional subspace is just a non-zero vector and all of its multiples by elements of the base field, so it contains $p-1$ nonzero vectors. A 2-dimensional subspace contains $p^2$ vectors, of which $p^2-1=(p-1)(p+1)$ are nonzero. No two distinct 1-dimensional subspaces have a nonzero vector in common, and every vector in the 2-dimensional subspace is in some 1-dimensional subspace, so there must be $p+1$ 1-dimensional subspaces contained in the 2-dimensional subspace, as was to be proved.